# QnA Maker - Oops!! Something went wrong. Please try again. If this error persists, please provide details via the feedback menu

Tags: botframework, azure-qna-maker

I am creating a new KB in my azure. I created a new QnA service but when I upload a `.tsv` file I get this error:

`Oops!! Something went wrong. Please try again. If this error persists, please provide details via the feedback menu.`

I deleted the service and created a new one  but I still get the same error. Has anyone else had this issue?

[Link to KB file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AofmcwPdWyKliiHx7ehKES8q_9GB3731/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Were you able to create q&a using UI in qnamaker.ai in that KB?

Comment: Also what might be helpful, would you be able to share your tsv? Per docs, [this is an example](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-sample-data-files/blob/master/qna-maker/data-source-formats/Scenario_Responses_Friendly.tsv) of the structure that you want your tsv to have.

Comment: Another thing to consider is the size of the file/number of Q&A's you're trying to import for your KB. For example, in the multi-turn conversation article, regarding using the sample Surface Pro manual pdf that they have it says that you need a higher than baseline pricing tier, "Multi-turn structure can be inferred only from URLs, PDF files, or DOCX files. For an example of structure, view an image of a Microsoft Surface user manual PDF file. Because of the size of this PDF file, the QnA Maker resource requires a Search pricing tier of B (15 indexes) or greater."

Comment: @RajeshSitaraman i was able to create a service using QnAmaker.ui in Azure. There are 6 KB's..not more than 7 to 8 qna's in them.

Comment: @Zeryth I have added an example tsv.

Comment: it is working now. I didn't change anything. I was just trying again and everything went smoothly